# What's the best way to move MySQL to Parse.com

Tags: mysql, parse-platform

I have an iOS app that currently uses MySQL as the database backend to store about 2000 records and 10,000 photos.  I want to refactor my Objective-C to use Parse instead of the current MySQL and I'm wondering what would be the best way to move my MySQL data to Parse?

Here is the current MySQL structure of my database.

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `mysqlToParsePlatform`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_authentication`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_authentication` (
  `authentication_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deny_access` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`authentication_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_categories`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `category_icon` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_news`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_news` (
  `news_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `news_content` text NOT NULL,
  `news_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `news_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `photo_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`news_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_photos`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_photos` (
  `photo_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `photo_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`photo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10167 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_ratings`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_ratings` (
  `rating_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `rating` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`rating_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=32 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_reviews`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_reviews` (
  `review_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `review` text NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`review_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_stores`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_stores` (
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `store_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `store_address` varchar(160) NOT NULL,
  `store_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `lat` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lon` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sms_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `featured` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2027 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `awesome_users`
--

CREATE TABLE `awesome_users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `login_hash` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_id` text NOT NULL,
  `twitter_id` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `deny_access` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `thumb_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `photo_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

Comment: You'll need to write a script that migrates the data. Parse is a non-relational database, so it's not something that can be done automatically.

Comment: You need to hire a consultant. This is _far_ too broad for a Q&A repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time looking for answers, trying to research migration services and looking into writting custom scripts, I decided to try the easiest route first.  And that worked!

Hopefully this will help others looking to move similar records from MySQL to Parse.

In order to get my 2,000+ stores records and 10,000+ photos out of the MySQL database, I went to phpMyAdmin and exported the `awesome_stores` and `awesome_photos` tables to two separate CSV files using the setting pictured below.

[image]
Once you have your CSV files, open your Parse Data Browser and go to the Core tab and look under the Data section pictured below and click on Import.

[image]

That will bring up the import dialog box.  That looks like this. Name your new Custom Class and then add your .CSV.  Make sure that phpMyAdmin does not add an extra line to head of your .csv.  If it does, you will get an error when trying to do the import to Parse.

[image]

Comment: Any regrets so far?